# Generate random matrix with elements having spatial co-relation

Tags: dataset, random-variable

I want to generate an $N\times N$ matrix where in each element is a processor parameter.

Each cell has a value (process parameter) associated with it which can be modeled as a Gaussian random variable with fixed mean and standard deviation.

Also there is a spatial co-relation coefficient between each of the cells based on distance given by :

$$\rho = e^{-\alpha\sqrt{(i-k)^2 + (j-l)^2}} \forall i,j,k,l  \in [1,N]$$

How do I write a program to generate  a random matrix with the following properties ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matrix is really just a vector with an unusual layout. Since you know the correlation between the elements of the matrix, you can write down the matrix as $N^2$ vector with the corresponding correlation matrix. You have means, correlations and variances, hence you fully define a Gaussian random vector. Generate it using the usual software and then rearrange the vector into a matrix. Just respect the original order which was used to define the correlation matrix.

Comment: I am completely new to this field, can you point me to some of the code/libraries which generate such vectors

Comment: Have you tried googling it? Generate multivariate normal will get you lots of hits. For R there is a function `mvrnorm` in the package **MASS**.